Generator outputs NaN values after one gradient update (Pytorch GAN)
I'm trying to build a simple pytorch GAN model.
My code for the generator, discriminator and trainer is shown below
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
    self.device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    self.model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum = 0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum = 0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum = 0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4, stride=1, bias=False),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.Flatten()
    )

  def rescale(self, x):
    out = x.clone() * 2.0 - 1.0
    return out

  def forward(self, data):
    assert not np.any(np.isnan(data.detach().cpu().numpy())), "Discriminator Received NaN Input"
    data = self.rescale(data)
    out = self.model(data)
    return out

class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self.device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    self.model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=100, out_channels=512, kernel_size=4, stride=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=0.9),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.Tanh()
    )
    self.activation_fn = nn.Tanh()

  def forward(self, data):
    assert not np.any(np.isnan(data.detach().cpu().numpy())), "Generator Received NaN Input"
    batch_size = data.size(0)
    data = data.view(batch_size, -1, 1, 1)
    #print(data.shape)
    #print(f"generator data: {data}")
    out = self.model(data)
    print(f"min: {torch.min(out)} max: {torch.max(out)}")
    return out

class DCGAN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
    super(DCGAN, self).__init__()
    self.discriminator = discriminator
    self.generator = generator
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.d_optim = optim.Adam(self.discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas =(0.5,0.999))
    self.g_optim = optim.Adam(self.generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002, betas =(0.5,0.999))
    self.loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()
    self.train_metrics = {
        'd_loss': Metrics.Mean(),
        'g_loss': Metrics.Mean(),
        'd_real_acc': Metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
        'd_fake_acc': Metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
        'g_acc': Metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
    }

  def run(self, epochs):
    loop_iteration = tqdm.tqdm(range(epochs))
    for iteration in loop_iteration:
      total_d_loss = 0
      total_g_loss = 0
      for idx, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        print(f"Idx: {idx}")
        d_loss, g_loss = self.train_step(imgs)
        total_d_loss += d_loss
        total_g_loss += g_loss
      print(f"Epoch: {iteration}, Discriminator Loss: {total_d_loss}, Generator Loss: {total_g_loss}")

  def train_step(self, real_images):
    #print(f"real imags: {real_images}")
    batch_size = real_images.size(0)
    real_predictions = self.discriminator(real_images)
    #print(fake_predictions)

    real_labels = torch.ones_like(real_predictions)
    real_noisy_labels = real_labels - 0.1 * torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(size=real_predictions.shape))
    real_noisy_labels = real_noisy_labels.to(torch.float32)
    """ Train Generator"""
    self.g_optim.zero_grad()
    self.d_optim.zero_grad()
    rlv = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_dim)
    generated_images = self.generator(rlv)
    print(f"generated_images: min: {torch.min(generated_images)} max: {torch.max(generated_images)}")
    fake_predictions = self.discriminator(generated_images)
    print(f"real_labels: min: {torch.min(real_labels)} max: {torch.max(real_labels)}")
    print(f"fake preds: min: {torch.min(fake_predictions)} max: {torch.max(fake_predictions)}")
    real_labels = real_labels.squeeze(-1)
    fake_predictions = fake_predictions.squeeze(-1)
    print(f"rl shape: {real_labels.shape} fp: {fake_predictions.shape}")
    g_loss = self.loss_fn(real_labels, fake_predictions)
    print(f"g_loss: {g_loss}")
    g_loss.backward()
    self.g_optim.step()

    """ Train Discriminator"""
    self.d_optim.zero_grad()
    self.g_optim.zero_grad()
    random_latent_vectors = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_dim)
    generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)
    print(f"generated_images: {generated_images}")
    real_predictions = self.discriminator(real_images)
    fake_predictions = self.discriminator(generated_images.clone().detach())
    #print(fake_predictions)

    real_labels = torch.ones_like(real_predictions)
    real_noisy_labels = real_labels - 0.1 * torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(size=real_predictions.shape))
    real_noisy_labels = real_noisy_labels.to(torch.float32)

    fake_labels = torch.zeros_like(fake_predictions)
    fake_noisy_labels = fake_labels + 0.1 * torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(size=fake_predictions.shape))
    fake_noisy_labels = fake_noisy_labels.to(torch.float32)


    d_real_loss = self.loss_fn(real_noisy_labels, real_predictions)
    d_fake_loss = self.loss_fn(fake_noisy_labels, fake_predictions)
    d_loss = (d_real_loss + d_fake_loss) / 2.0
    d_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    self.d_optim.step()

    
    #print(f"types: real_predictions {real_predictions.dtype} real_noisy_labels: {real_noisy_labels.dtype}")

    return d_loss.detach().item(), g_loss.detach().item()

The problem is that after one gradient update to the Generator, it outputs NaN values in the next update iteration. I printed the generator weights per iteration, and saw that it becomes NaN after one update iteration.
I tried to tweak the learning rate but didn't work. I also omitted the generator update phase from the code, and only trained the discriminator, which actually worked successfully, so I believe the problem is in the gradient update step of the generator.
Any help would be much appreciated.
